# Converting an enum to an array of custom literals

Tags: typescript, enums

Assume this:

```
export enum Day {
  Monday = 111,
  Tuesday = 222,
  Wednesday = 333,
  Thursday = 444,
  Friday = 555,
  Saturday = 666,
  Sunday = 777,
}

Object.values(Day)
  .filter(v => typeof v === 'number') // or filter(Number)
  .map(numeric => console.log('numeric', numeric))
  // more code to come
```

I am trying to build an array of custom objects out of an enum, such as `{ id: 111, label: 'Monday' }` and I am struggling with types.

When hovering over `numeric` I would expect the type to be `number`, or maybe `Day`, but never unioned with `| string`, as I am filtering strings out just before it.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use type guard before `map` if you want typescript to infer the actual type for `numeric`, e.g.

```
function isNumber(v: unknown): v is number {
  return typeof v === 'number'
}
Object.values(Day)
  .filter(isNumber) // or filter(Number)
  .map(numeric => console.log('numeric', numeric)) // numeric is number
```

Comment: Relevant docs: [Assertion Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

Answer (score 1):

The key is in how TypeScript converts `enum` code into JavaScript:

```
export var Day;
(function (Day) {
    Day[Day["Monday"] = 111] = "Monday";
    Day[Day["Tuesday"] = 222] = "Tuesday";
    Day[Day["Wednesday"] = 333] = "Wednesday";
    Day[Day["Thursday"] = 444] = "Thursday";
    Day[Day["Friday"] = 555] = "Friday";
    Day[Day["Saturday"] = 666] = "Saturday";
    Day[Day["Sunday"] = 777] = "Sunday";
})(Day || (Day = {}));
```

You can verify this for yourself by looking at the JS output in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgTygbwLACgpQLIHsQAmiUAvFAIyUA0GWAKmMAM5FJkBMnNmUA6sARDNWpKAGYJ3egAswAJxbEyAFlVSoAMTkBLEWQCsh9QGU4AF3l6oANlsmwhJVADsr7gF8MQA)

Basically, it makes sure that an enum's values can be looked up in either direction. What is `Day.Monday`? Why it's `111`. But what is `Day['111']`? Ah, it's `'Monday'`.

This works because the expressions in the inner square brackets resolve to the value being assigned. For example, `Day["Monday"] = 111` resolves to `111`, so `Day[Day["Monday"] = 111] = "Monday";` is essentially shorthand for:

```
Day["Monday"] = 111;
Day[111] = "Monday";
```

So when you pass `Day` to `Object.values` you aren't just getting `[111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777]` like you might expect. Instead, you're getting `["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777]`. TypeScript interprets this as being of type `(string | Day)[]`.

Comment: I understand how enums are transpiled so to enable bidirectional lookup. My question was why I still get the union if I first narrowed the type down to a number. So the lexical values shouldn't pass. through to `map`

Comment: @user776686 you used filter and created a subset of your `(string|number)[]` but TS does not understand that this specific filter-function narrows the type down. see [ABOS' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70910472/6567275) and [pilchards comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910031/converting-an-enum-to-an-array-of-custom-literals#comment125356998_70910472).